# Firebase Dynamic Links are not working on Flutter IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

I have integrated Firebase Dynamic Links into my Flutter app. The feature works just fine on Android but it does not work on the IOS app. I can't generate links (it returns null). When I open the generated link from the android app, I get this warning

```
iOS app '234' lacks App ID Prefix. UniversalLinks is not enabled for the app. Learn more.
```

and that is linked to the documentation of the [absence of team ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug#ios-team-id-absent).

This is the AASA file generated by Firebase

```
{"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[{"appID":"teamID.com.company.appname","paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]}]}}
```

Info.plist file

```
<array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>Bundle ID</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.company.appname</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
    <array>
        <string>https://mylink.com/link</string>
    </array>
```

code for creating the link

```
      print('$_baseUrl$path?$queryParam=$value');
      var parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
        uriPrefix: _baseUrl,
        link: Uri.parse('$_baseUrl$path?$queryParam=$value'),
        androidParameters: const AndroidParameters(
          packageName: 'com.company.appname',
          minimumVersion: 0,
        ),
        iosParameters: const IOSParameters(
            bundleId: 'com.company.appname',
            minimumVersion: '0',
            appStoreId: 'appstoreid'),
      );
      final shortLink =
          await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildShortLink(parameters);
      var shortUrl = shortLink;
      print('short link ==== ${shortUrl.previewLink.toString()}');
      return shortUrl.previewLink.toString();
```

I double-checked the team ID and app store ID of the app, and both are correct. Any idea what might be the issue here?